# How does one implement a method in Binary Tree in returning the next node visited after variable?

Tags: java, binary-tree

[image]

```
Preorder: / * + a b – c d + e f
Inorder: a + b * c – d / e + f
Postorder: a b + c d - * e f + /
```

Say we have this tree. I already got the code for printing out the orders; Preorder, Inorder and Postorder. Now whats left is the problem, the user is asked to input *Preorder next to what character?*, lets say the user entered the letter a, so the output should be

```
Preorder next to what character?: a
Preordernext(a) = b
```

and so on to Inorder and Postorder, now the problem is i cant seem to locate the next node from a specific node.

```
System.out.print("Preorder next of what character: ");
char q = scn.next().charAt(0);
System.out.print("PreorderNext("+q+")| ");
binaryTree.searchPostOrder(q);
```

So far this is what i came up with and I received no result aside from blank...

```
public void searchPostOrder(char kwanix) {
        searchPostorder(root, kwanix);
    }
    private char searchPostorder(Node node, char kwanix) {
        if (node.getData() == kwanix) {
            if (node.getLeft() != null) {
                if (node.getLeft().equals(kwanix)) {
                    kwanix = node.getData();
                }
            }
            if (node.getRight() != null) {
                if (node.getRight().equals(kwanix)) {
                    kwanix = node.getData();
                }
            }
        }
        return kwanix;
    }
```

This is the result after running the program

```
Post Order| d c b a 
Pre order| a c d b 
In order| c d a b 

Preorder next of what character: a
PreorderNext(a)|
```

Answer (score 3):

One (simple) solution:

You figured that your tree "walk" leads to different results.

```
Preorder: / * + a b – c d + e f
Inorder: a + b * c – d / e + f
Postorder: a b + c d - * e f + /
```

Note that this output contains **all** your nodes, just in different order. And look: in the sequence for the pre order row ... `b` comes right after `a`!

In other words: one simple solution is:

- you pick the order strategy the user wants
- you walk your tree in that order
- when you find `a`, you continue to the next node (that is a leaf), and that is what you return as result

Comment: Wait, how does one continue to the next node and only print the next node? Thats also one of the problems.

Comment: As I said: *traversing* your tree in a specific walking mode *results* in a sequence of all nodes, just with different order. Start by having your *walking" code return a List for example. Then you do `List<Node> inOrderNodes = getNodesInOrder();` ... and then you can just walk through that list.

Comment: Ohhh I see, I thought there was a way without using List/Array, i'm sorry for not getting that. My bad. Thank you

Comment: Well, array/List are just one option. That method could also return an Iterable object.

Comment: FINALLY GOT IT!! MAN I LOVE PROGRAMMING

Answer (score 2):

My approach will be :

1. I will move through all nodes and store value of only those nodes containing characters and not the operators.
   Example

   Preorder: / * + a b – c d + e f

   myArray => a b c d e f

My array will contain only characters : `{a , b ,  c,  d,  e , f}`.

2. Then I will start a loop through index 0 to length of array.length-1 if encounter userSymbol then

Print [index+1]

else

Print empty.

Comment: There are no operators, only characters, so the "operator" signs are not really operators but characters only. I thought of doing that but is it also possible to do the problem in the BST way, I wanna try it that way if its possible otherwise i'll go with the solution using array. Thank you.